# const vs var for function assignments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constants, user-defined-functions

So often I see functions being assigned to variables in JavaScript like this:

```
var square = function(number) {
  return number * number;
}
```

Is there any benefit to using `const` instead if the variable will never be reassigned to another function or value? Is there any reason not to use `const`?

```
const square = function(number) {
  return number * number;
}
```

Comment: const is a ES-6 notation. Not sure about the differences though. Would like to know more about this one.

Comment: I can't speak for any performance benefits, but I definitely like to use `const` as a safeguard for any identifiers I know should not be reassigned.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Is there any particular reason you feel its use would be any different with a function reference than a "normal" variable?

Comment: Please note that just because an identifier has been `const`d does not mean the referenced object is immune to changes, e.g. you can set `square.foo = 'bar';` and it will work normally. If you also want to prevent this, use `Object.freeze(square)` too

Comment: Well I had something to add in regards to performance and quirks between strict mode and not. Think Ill add the answer to the unanswer duplicate.

Comment: @at: I just did, but usually it doesn't matter much which question exactly is linked in the box. The comments (which were unfortunately auto-deleted) are often enough more helpful.